# Как написать UI тесты - проверить, добавился ли элемент на страницу?

Tags: javascript, kotlin, юнит-тесты, test-automation

У меня есть проект на Kotlin JS.
Я хочу написать тесты для него, протестировав, например, добавляются ли элементы DOM на страницу при клике на кнопку.

Что-нибудь типа такого:

```
@Test
fun myTest() {
  when{
     window.onLoad().await()
     window.getElementById("#myBtn").click()
  }
  then {
     window.hasElementById("#myElement")
  }
}
```

Вроде как нужны headless браузеры. Только не могу разобраться, как их подключить и взаимодействовать с ними (не нашел ни одного подобного примера с ними на котлине).

Comment: я только хотел сказать такие тесты не эффективны против ситуаций, когда кнопка добавилась, но ее по какой то причине нет на экране, например не влезла или скрыта за другой элемент, сквозь который на нее не нажать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ есть же разные уровни тестирования. Роберт Мартин рекомендовал тестить UI, рассматривая его как апи, через призму того, есть ли элементы. Двигаться они могут часто - поэтому тесты на скриншотах и т.п. придётся постоянно менять. А подобные помогут проверить базовую логику достаточно точно